# Просчет промежутков времени между выполняемыми работами

Tags: c#, циклы, условия

Дано время:

начало смены 20:00   конец смены 08:00

начало обеда 02:00   конец обеда 03:00

начало ремонты 21:00  конец ремонта 22:00

прочее начало  05:00  прочее конец 7:00

Общее время смены 12 часов, за вычетом всех работ составляет 8 часов

Необходимо просчитать промежутки времени по порядку.
Т.е. смена началась в 20:00, а ремонт в 21:00 (промежуток составил 1 час смены)
ремонт закончился в 22:00, а обед начался в 02:00 (промежуток составил 4 часа смены) и обед закон. в 03:00 а прочие дела начались в 05:00 (промежуток составил 2 часа) и прочие дела закончились в 7:00 и смена закончилась в 8:00 (промежуток равен 1 час) (общие промежутки складываем 1+4+2+1=8)

Теперь сама загвоздка:
Т.к. время может полностью меняться, т.е обед может быть позже, а ремонт начаться раньше и т.д. Не получается выхватить правильные значения. 
Вот пример чего мудрил, а именно с условиями if:

```
           //смена
            TimeSpan dns = dt1.TimeOfDay; //начало 
            TimeSpan dnes = dt2.TimeOfDay; //конец
            //обед
            TimeSpan dno = tob1.TimeOfDay; //начало 
            TimeSpan dneo = tob2.TimeOfDay;
            //ремонт
            TimeSpan dnr = trem1.TimeOfDay; //начало 
            TimeSpan dner = trem2.TimeOfDay; //конец
            //повременно
            TimeSpan dnp = tpov1.TimeOfDay; //начало 
            TimeSpan dnep = tpov2.TimeOfDay; //конец


 if (dt1 == trem1)
            {
                numtot_smrem = 0;
            }
                else
                {
                    if (dt1 == tpov1)
                    {
                        numtot_smpov = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (dt1 < trem1)
                        {
                            TimeSpan Ttotrem = trem1 - dt1;
                            numtot_smrem = Ttotrem.TotalHours;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                         if (dt1>trem1)
                          {
                              TimeSpan Ttotpov = dt1 - trem1;
                              numtot_smrem = 24 - Ttotpov.TotalHours;
                          }
                            if (dt1 < tpov1)
                            {
                                TimeSpan Ttotpov = tpov1 - dt1;
                                numtot_smpov = Ttotpov.TotalHours;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (dt1 > tpov1)
                                {
                                    TimeSpan Ttotpov = dt1 - tpov1;
                                    numtot_smpov = 24 - Ttotpov.TotalHours;
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    if (dt1 < tob1)
                                    {
                                        TimeSpan Ttotobd = tob1 - dt1;
                                        numtot_smobd = Ttotobd.TotalHours;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (dt1 > tob1)
                                        {
                                            TimeSpan Ttotobd = dt1 - tob1;
                                            numtot_smobd = Ttotobd.TotalHours;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Скорее всего необходимо это все засунуть в цикл while, не?

Comment: Ух... слишком сильная вложенность if => тяжело к пониманию-(

Comment: Да, if в if....

Answer (score 2):

1. Я бы создал бы класс `TimeInterval` и туда бы положил: Время начала, Время конца, Тип интервала(Обед, ремонт и т д) и метод, который возвращает разницу.
   Таким образом вы избавитесь от дублирования кода. Возможно, имеет смысл так же переопределить HashCode и Equal, что бы сортировка корректно работала, если она вам нужна.
2. Далее все эти объекты поместил бы в какую-нибудь коллекцию, пробежался бы циклом `foreach`, вызвав метод получения разницы и просуммировал его.

По идее, это то, чего вы хотите, как я понял.

Comment: Немного не понял про тип интервала между обедом, работой и прочим. Общие смену я уже просчитал, вычил из этого работу, обед и прочее.